# How to release a subdirectory of a Git repository as a new Git repository to external users?

Tags: git, repository

How to release a subdirectory of a Git repository as a new Git repository to external users?

I have a Git repository `~/repo.git`; It has subdirectories `~/repo.git/sub1` and `~/repo.git/sub2`.  I now need to release/export/publish (or whatever appropriate verb) `sub1` to a group of friends, so they can see and use programs and data in `sub1`.  It'll be nice if they can push my updates done in `repo.git` to this publicized `sub1`.

What's a good solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The [`git subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/subtree) command can be used to do this.

The documentation is in [`git-subtree.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).

Comment: `subtree` should do what you've described, but if your friends are using `sub1` standalone, maybe you should too? Then you can all have the same workflow on it. In which case, you could use `git subtree` or `git filter-branch` to do the original split.

Answer (score 0):

I would use submodules to manage this relationship. They capture the exact version that you you are using. You can use filter branch to remove your private branch out of clone of this repo. Then just delete that directory in your repo and add the submodule that points to the new repo you just created.

Comment: Submodules seem not exactly suits my use case, as I'm not introducing an external project into my project, but rather I am exposing part of my project as a separate and publicized project.